# Define enum as flag with an or

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to create an enum as flag. I come from C#, and I want to create an equivalent in C++. I found how to create an enum as a flag in C++, but not how to re-use a member for another member value.

I do not know how to ask my question clearly so here's what I'm trying to do (C# code):

```
[Flags]
enum myEnum
{
    TypeA = 0x01,
    TypeB = 0x02,
    TypeC = 0x04,
    TypeAB = TypeA | TypeB
}
```

What I wrote in C++:

```
enum myEnum
{
    TypeA = 0x01,
    TypeB = 0x02,
    TypeC = 0x04,
    TypeAB = TypeA | TypeB
};
inline myEnum operator|(myEnum a, myEnum b)
{
    return static_cast<myEnum>(static_cast<int>(a) | static_cast<int>(b));
}
```

But I have an error :

> redefinition of 'TypeA '

**Edit:**

I'm very new to C++ and I forgot the compiler. There is my environment:

- I'm working on windows 10
- with Visual studio 2017
- I compile for android with Clang 3.8 and I target KitKat 4.4
- I'm using C++ 11

**Edit2:**

I identified the problem. In my namespace I have a class name typeA:

In a .h :

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    namespace myOtherNameSpace
    {
        class typeA {...}
    }
}
```

There is a conflict between both. Can I modify my enum to keep `myEnum.TypeA` or should I rename this member ?

Comment: What compiler do you use? Your snippet should compile just fine.

Comment: This compiles fine for me, can you post a complete code example that reproduces this error, also what compiler are you using?

Comment: You don't need to implement a custorm `operator|` for your `enum` since it is not a ("strongly typed") scoped `enum`.

Comment: Yes, please provide a [mcve]. Your code builds fine for me http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61d1123fa137fbd2

Comment: @Swordfish - You do if you want to assign the result back to `myEnum` without a cast.

Comment: @StoryTeller To use it in an initialization of an enumerator ... shouldn't it be `constexpr`?

Comment: @Swordfish - It's not used in definition of the enumeration. The enumerators are just names of specific values from the underlying type. So when `TypeAB = TypeA | TypeB` is defined `|` is the built-in integer or operator, while `myEnum e = TypeA | TypeB;` would in fact use the overloaded operator (or cause an error if the operator isn't present). Same tokens mean different things in different contexts. Gotta love C++, huh?

Comment: I added informations about my environment

Comment: Psychic debugging attempt: You haven't shown us the whole code.  In particular, you haven't shown us the bit where you write `enum myEnum2 { TypeA = 0x01 };`.  Your problem is that in C++, with simple enums like this, the enumerators are not scoped to the enumeration, but are symbols in the global namespace.  If you want them scoped to the enumeration (which is useful), you need `enum class myEnum ...`.

Comment: @Swordfish - Interesting. They probably find the operator via ADL. I wonder...

Comment: @StoryTeller this code is from my `.h`, it only contain this enum in a my namespace. It does not build for me.

Comment: @StoryTeller with `constexpr` I identified the problem. In my nameplace I have a class named TypeA. I don't know well c++, in C# it's possible to have `class TypeA` and `myEnum.TypeA`. Is it possible to have an enum member with same name as a class ?

Comment: Use a `enum class` if you don't want the enumerators populate the surrounding namespace.

Comment: @Swordfish it works with `enum class` ! Thank you very much. I'll check the difference between `enum and `enum class` for the next time.

Comment: @Swordfish - You know, I'm not so sure anymore `cl` is wrong here. This may warrant a language lawyer question

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried, but i can't figure it out from the std either. Lets call it a tie ;)

Comment: @Swordfish - We're no quitters! I found the relevant passage [\[dcl.enum\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#5) . The **tl;dr** of it is that the `|` should be the built-in between the `{  }` of the enum definition. GCC and Clang are correct :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I just tried to compile the original code again. It works! But i swear i did nothing different the first time i tried and intellisense still complains about `TypeA | TypeB` not being a constant expression. O.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this topic, there is the answer found thanks to Swordfish :

Replace `enum` by `enum class`

```
enum class myEnum
{
    TypeA = 0x01,
    TypeB = 0x02,
    TypeC = 0x04,
    TypeAB = TypeA | TypeB
};
```

With simple `enum` you can write `myEnum e = TypeA`, so if a class is named `TypeA`, there is a conflit and you have a compilation error.

With `enum class` you must specify the enum `myEnum e = myEnum::TypeA`. This can avoid some errors and allow to have a class named `TypeA`

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with your code - so maybe a different issue.

However, instead of the casts, etc. you may just specify the underlying enum, so your enum becomes

```
enum myEnum : int
{
    TypeA = 0x01,
    TypeB = 0x02,
    TypeC = 0x04,
    TypeAB = TypeA | TypeB
};
```

UPDATE: that code may not work on an older compiler such as clang 3.8 - since it's a 'modern' c++ feature.

Comment: and is utterly useless without `operator|()` if it should be used as flags.